# Xaml Rendering in IIS not working (but in IISExpress)

Tags: c#, wpf, iis, iis-express

For my application, I am rendering some charts (WPF based) on the server and sending them back to the client.
I recently migrated the app to NET Core, which seemed to work fine until the very end when I deployed things on IIS. There, the charts are empty. However, when hosting the app in IISExpress, everything works smoothly.

I am now wondering what the differences between IIS and IISexpress are when it comes to graphics.

The code I am executing:

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)control.Width, (int)control.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
renderTargetBitmap.Clear(); 

renderTargetBitmap.Render((Visual)control); 

var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(); 

var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap); 
encoder.Frames.Add(bitmapFrame); 
encoder.Save(memoryStream);
```

The code is run in an STA thread, for the sake of this problem the chart library doesn't matter, it is also supposed to work for a simple grid with a background color..

As I said, the code runs a) in a (non-wpf) console application b) in IIS Express c) in IIS before migrating to NET Core.

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: Just a note, calling Clear() on a newly created RenderTargetBitmap seems redundant. You would usually also use a control's ActualWidth and ActualHeight instead of Width and Height to determine the bitmap size.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-most-common-technologies-not-supported-by-microsoft-8675c409bde2 Server side usage of WPF is never supported. It might work in some cases, but must break in most.

Comment: Could you find any error message in event viewer?Besides could you get it work in either in-process or out-process mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution, there is a well hidden compatibility switch available

https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Compatibility

Service/Non-interactive Window Stations
Rendering will continue by default, irrespective of the presence of display devices. Unless the WPF API's being used are short-lived (like rendering to a bitmap), it can lead to a CPU spike. If an application running inside a service would like to receive the 'default' WPF behavior, i.e., no rendering in the absence of display devices, then it should set to true

In short, add a new file "runtimeconfig.template.json" to your project with the content

```
{ "configProperties": { "Switch.System.Windows.Media.ShouldRenderEvenWhenNoDisplayDevicesAreAvailable": true } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues.
It's possible that a control is not fully rendered. And there is no event provided that would inform us about rendering finished (as Loaded event is too early).
So the answer is: I guess that IISExpress is a bit slower then IIS).

If I'm right then here are workarounds that may work:

- try `await Task.Delay(1000)` before rendering,
- so nasty, but working: open a transparent window, and make the control a content of this window. Close it on rendered event. (I had a charting library that required visual tree existing, to be correctly working, and this was a working workaround). You'll need to make you console app to use WPF.
- Or, if you make your console app using WPF, it may be enough to call your rendering method with `Dispatcher`, on a low priority. But for a WPF app, that didn't have a window opened, you'd need to start `Dispatcher` first.

Comment: I am trying out your ideas, but so far without much success. Do you have an example how to properly start the dispatcher manually?